# Unable to use Memcached in Django 1.11 (cannot import name 'get_cache')

Tags: django, memcached, python-3.6

I want to use Memcached in my Django 1.11 project. I am using Python 3.6.
I have installed memcached on my mac OSX terminal with Homebrew. After that I installed its python bindings:

```
pip install python-memchached==1.58
```

I then add the necessary configurations to my settings.py project file:

```
 CACHES = {
  'default': {
     'BACKEND':'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
     'LOCATION':'127.0.0.1:11211',
  }
}
```

I two terminals, one for my local host and the second one for memcached:

`memcached -l 127.0.0.1:11211`

When I refresh my web page I get the following error:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 15, 2017 - 10:47:30
Django version 1.11.6, using settings 'educa.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/comp/Desktop/Dev/educa/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/utils.py", line 65, in __getitem__
return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/comp/Desktop/Dev/educa/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 126, in 
get_package_libraries
module = import_module(entry[1])
File 
"/Users/comp/Desktop/Dev/educa/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", 
line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in 
_find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in 
exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in 
_call_with_frames_removed
File "/Users/comp/Desktop/Dev/educa/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/memcache_status/templatetags/memcache_status_tags.py", line 
3, in <module>
from django.core.cache import get_cache
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_cache'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/comp/Desktop/Dev/educa/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/Users/comp/Desktop/Dev/educa/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/Users/comp/Desktop/Dev/educa/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_response
response = response.render()
File "/Users/comp/Desktop/Dev/educa/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/response.py", line 107, in render
self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/Users/comp/Desktop/Dev/educa/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/response.py", line 82, in rendered_content
template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
File "/Users/comp/Desktop/Dev/educa/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/response.py", line 64, in resolve_template
return select_template(template, using=self.using)
File "/Users/comp/Desktop/Dev/educa/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/loader.py", line 44, in select_template
engines = _engine_list(using)
File "/Users/comp/Desktop/Dev/educa/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/loader.py", line 72, in _engine_list
return engines.all() if using is None else [engines[using]]
File "/Users/comp/Desktop/Dev/educa/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/utils.py", line 89, in all
return [self[alias] for alias in self]
File "/Users/comp/Desktop/Dev/educa/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/utils.py", line 89, in <listcomp>
return [self[alias] for alias in self]
File "/Users/comp/Desktop/Dev/educa/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/utils.py", line 80, in __getitem__
engine = engine_cls(params)
File "/Users/comp/Desktop/Dev/educa/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 30, in __init__
options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
File "/Users/comp/Desktop/Dev/educa/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 48, in 
get_templatetag_libraries
libraries = get_installed_libraries()
File "/Users/comp/Desktop/Dev/educa/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 113, in 
get_installed_libraries
for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
File "/Users/comp/Desktop/Dev/educa/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 130, in 
get_package_libraries
"trying to load '%s': %s" % (entry[1], e)
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template 
library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 
'memcache_status.templatetags.memcache_status_tags': cannot import 
name 'get_cache'
[15/Oct/2017 10:47:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 131841
```

Can anyone point me to a solution for my issue ?

Comment: The problem seems to be coming from the `memcache_status` package. Are you sure you installed an up-to-date version of that? Django removed the `get_cache` function in 1.8, and `memcache_status` was upgraded earlier this year to be compatible.

Comment: I updated the memcache_status using the command:
pip inatall git+git://github.com/bartTC/django-memcache-status.git.
This solved the get_cache error. But now when I try to access the admin page I get this error:
     File "/Users/comp/Desktop/Dev/educa/lib/python3.6/site-        packages/memcache_status/templatetags/memcache_status_tags.py", line 106, in prettyname
    return ' '.join([word.capitalize() for word in name.split('_')])
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'